# Before & After Content - After Content directly below Before Content when using require_once

Tags: php, functions, content, include

I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I am using require_once to place content before and after the page content on my homepage. The before content works perfectly and displays fine. If I use text for the after content such as $aftercontent: 'this is my text';

However, if I attempt another require_once call the after content is situated directly beneath my before content, and before The $content. Code below.

```
// -----------------------------------------
// HOMEPAGE HERO & FOOTER CALL

function wpdev_before_after($content) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
        $beforecontent = require_once ( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/moon-child/includes/hero-registered-include.php' );
        $aftercontent = require_once ( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/moon-child/includes/footer-registered-include.php' );
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
    } else {
        $beforecontent = require_once ( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/moon-child/includes/hero-unregistered-include.php' );
        $aftercontent = require_once ( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/moon-child/includes/footer-unregistered-include.php' );
        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
    }

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpdev_before_after');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file you want to attach (eg. `footer-registered-include.php`) print/display some text, this text will be displayed in the time you include the file.

To assign to the variable the content displayed by the included file you should:

1. turn on output buffering
2. include file
3. contents of the output buffer and end output buffering

```
function wpdev_before_after($content)
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() )
    {
        ob_start();
        require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/hero-registered-include.php' );
        $beforecontent = ob_get_contents();
        ob_clean();
        // -- OR --
        // $beforecontent = ob_get_clean();
        // ob_start();

        include_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/footer-registered-include.php' );
        $aftercontent = ob_get_clean();

        $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;
    }
    // else {
    // ...
    // }
    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wpdev_before_after');
```

---

References:

- [get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)

Comment: This half worked. It placed the hero at the top, but then duplicated the hero and then placed the footer beneath that.

Comment: This works! However, it is missing the Else statement that indicates to load 2 different includes if the user is not logged in. Can I just copy this code to the Else statement or?

What is happening here exactly? What was stopping my code from working?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the same - start buffering on before `include`/`require` and read buffer contents after.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Can you elaborate on why the buffering plays such a big role in making this work? For example, if I used text instead of an include no buffering is required. Just trying to figure out what is happening.

Comment: The `the_content` filter accepts the content of the post as a parameter and **returns it** after an optional modification.
It (post content) will be displayed later. Let's say you have `echo 'text from hero file';` in `hero-registered.php` and `echo 'something in footer file';` in `footer-registed.php`.
The code: `$before= require_one('hero-registered.php'); $after= require_one('hero-registered.php'); $content= $before.$content.$after;` will load and execute the first script, the text will be displayed "_text from hero file_", to `$before` variable will be [...]

Comment: [...] will be assigned an int or boolean value (it will NOT contain the content displayed by the file). The second script will be read and executed, it will be displayed "_something in footer file_" (to `$after` variable the content displayed by the script also will NOT be assigned). Then the assignment `$content= $before.$content.$after;` and the new `$content` will be returned. Other filters will be applied (if they exist) and after that `$content` will be displayed (**the results of both files** _hero-registered.php_, _footer-registered.php_  **were displayed earlier**).